# AWS Lambda process Stripe charge

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, lambda, stripe-payments, aws-lambda

I'm new to Lambda and trying to figure out how to process Stripe charge in Lambda function.

My app creates token from Stripe API and now I need to send that token to Lambda function to execute `Stripe.customers.create` and `Stripe.charges.create`.

Here are the issues I'm having

1. I'm not sure how to load `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>` into Lambda function so I can use `Stripe` function
2. Would love to get a sample code to charge credit card by token

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't want to load Stripe.js into Lambda here, as that's meant to be used in the browser; rather, you'll want to use the [`stripe-node` library](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node) for this.

You'll find an example here: https://github.com/TaylorBriggs/stripe-lambda

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I actually saw them before but still not sure how to run `npm install stripe --save` on Lambda function. Can I install stripe on Lambda UI?

Comment: @user7724980 You'll need to create a deployment package: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-create-deployment-pkg.html. If you're having trouble with this, I recommend you open a new SO question (as this isn't specific to Stripe) and/or reach out directly to Amazon's support.